# How could I detect beacons with different proximity UUIDs?

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I am now developing an beacon app. But when I need to integrate other beacons with different proximity UUIDs into my app. When I do as follows:

```
NSArray *uuids = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"####-####-###1", @"####-####-###2", nil];
for (NSString *uuidString in uuids) {
CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:uuidString] identifier:identifier];
region.notifyOnEntry = entry;
region.notifyOnExit = exit;
region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
[_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
}
--------------------------------------

ESTBeaconRegion* region = [[ESTBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"F7826DA6-4FA2-4E98-8024-BC5B71E0893E"]identifier:@"EstimoteSampleRegion"];
 ESTBeaconRegion* region1 = [[ESTBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"3A04104E-06E3-48BE-85D8-D0FF574FAE71"]identifier:@"EstimoteSampleRegion1"];
      [self.beaconManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
      [self.beaconManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region1];
```

it can only track #2 beacons, because #2 overwrite #1. So could anyone tell me how to  detect beacons with different proximity UUIDs? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can simply create another CLBeaconRegion and start monitoring it

Comment: I change it, but it does not work, see new edited question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, I missed the loop in your original code - it should work. Have you tried one of the beacon monitoring apps from the app Store, such as "Locate IB"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the monitoring code is that it is using the same identifier field for each region.  This field must be unique, otherwise the second region will overwrite the first.  Try changing the code to keep the identifier unique.  Like this:

```
NSArray *uuids = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"####-####-###1", @"####-####-###2", nil];
for (NSString *uuidString in uuids) {
  CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:uuidString] 
                             identifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"unique-identifier-for-uuid-%@",uuidString]];
  region.notifyOnEntry = entry;
  region.notifyOnExit = exit;
  region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
  [_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
}
```

Comment: I change it, but it does not work, see new edited question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have changed code below: ----------;it does not work, could you help me, thank u